# excel vlookup shows #n/a but I see the value is there

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an excel vlookup and for some reason it always has #n/a even though I can see the search value is there, even when I look at the same table. Could it be an excel version issue, or share drive, or oneDrive? What is wrong with what I'm doing?

```
spreadsheet:
tab sheet1:

a               b           c                  d
comp           id          id2                msg           =VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A2:D35549,2,FALSE)
device1        83          398-usa            ab-cd-de
device2        84          0045-dn            ab-34-aa
device3        56          0045-ab            about


tab data:

a               b           c                  d
comp           id          id2                msg
device         83          398-usa            ab-cd-de
device2        84          0045-dn            ab-34-aa
device3        56          0045-ab            about
```

I can see that looking up b2 in sheet1 should find the info in the data tab.  Wy does it show n/a#

Comment: `VLOOKUP` would work if `id` were the *leftmost* column in the data tab. Use `INDEX`/`MATCH`, or `XLOOKUP` if your version of Excel supports it.

Comment: Use XLOOKUP instead of VLOOKUP.